# Pandas Aggregation: Putting Sums of unique objects into a new DF

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to extract the unique Non-Numeric elements (e.g. Position) in a column and combine them in a dataframe with the sum of their respective Numeric elements (e.g. Salaries)

Given a certain file e.g. this one:

```
Position,Experience in Years,Salary
Middle Management,5,5000
Lower Management,2,3000
Upper Management,1,7000
Middle Management,5,5000
Middle Management,7,7000
Upper Management,10,12000
Lower Management,2,2000
Middle Management,5,5001
Upper Management,7,10000
```

I defined the following function that takes the filepath as input and it works but it pairs up the sum with the wrong position - does someone know how to fix this?

```
def Aggregation(filePath):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    uniques = dataframe['Position'].unique() #returns 
    sum_list = []

    for i in range(0,len(uniques)):
        iteration_sum = dataframe.groupby('Position')['Salary'].sum()[i]
        sum_list.append(iteration_sum)
        
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(uniques)
    
    column_values = pd.Series(sum_list)
    new_df.insert(loc=1, column='Sum', value=column_values)

    return(sum_list)

Aggregation(filePath)
```

The output should basically be a dataframe looking like this

```
Position, Sum of Salary
Lower Management, 5000
Middle Management, 22001
Upper Management, 29000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function should be a lot simplified, only added [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to new DataFrame with column name `Sum of Salary`:

```
def Aggregation(filePath):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    return dataframe.groupby('Position')['Salary'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum of Salary')
```